# Ajax on nginx causes 404 not found

Tags: html, ajax, nginx

I'm using ajax to update a value without refreshing the page.
When I use this html code the website gives an 404 not found error. But when I leave the script tag out of the html, the site works fine and show the p tag. What am i doing wrong in the script tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Smart_home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="verbruik">
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("verbruik").innerHTML =
                    this.responseText;
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", "/home/pi/smart_home/ajax_info.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
            setTimeout(loadDoc, 2000);
        }
        loadDoc();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `/home/pi` your local filesystem? Surely your not serving `/` as the webroot, else it would be `Hacked_home` in no time

Comment: Your server can't find `/home/pi/smart_home/ajax_info.txt`, probably because it's looking relative from the web root. So Nginx returns a 404 which you write to your `<div id="verbruik">`. That's what makes it look like your page is showing a 404, while in reality you just show the 404 of `/home/pi/smart_home/ajax_info.txt`

Comment: @NullDev Thank you! I putted the ajax_info.txt in the webroot folder and now its working